# Wrong setInterval() function in react-native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am trying to use a periodic function using `setInterval` in my react-native app (I am aiming for iOS for now). I am using react-navigation and I would like to stop my interval when I navigate to another screen. To do this I have to use 'clearInterval' outside 'useEffect', here is what I found :
https://sebhastian.com/setinterval-react/

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (intervalId) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      setIntervalId(0);
      return;
    }
    const newIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    }, 1000);
    setIntervalId(newIntervalId);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>The component has been rendered for {count} seconds</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        {intervalId ? "Stop counting" : "Start counting"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My problem is that when I use the `setInterval()` function, it returns a NodeJS.Timer object that is not assignable to my state variable:

```
Argument of type 'Timer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number | undefined>'.ts(2345)
```

I saw a lot of react native examples using window `setInterval()` implicitly so I don't understand why I can't do the same, window object is unknown in my code.
Is there a way to "force" react to use `window.setInterval()` or is there a workaround with NodeJS.Timer object ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to use `useRef` here, the `id` would be fine as is.  Unless you wanted for some reason to access outside the `useEffect`.

Comment: you can remove interval by clearInterval(id). if you really wanted to, add inervalRef as a dependency

Comment: Yeah I explained poorly my problem, I need to clear the timer outside 'useEffect', I edited the post to clarify this point.

Comment: `stop my interval when I navigate to another screen.`  But that would happen anyway, as the component gets unmounted.

Comment: From the doc of react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/ : 'Consider a stack navigator with screens A and B. After navigating to A, its componentDidMount is called. When pushing B, its componentDidMount is also called, but A remains mounted on the stack and its componentWillUnmount is therefore not called.'

Comment: @Ewlan  Ah, yes, React Native,.  Op wants -> `useFocusEffect`..

Comment: But to use 'useFocusEffect' I need a reference to the timer, as it would be outside the scope where I declared it. And here is my problem, 'setInterval' doesn't return the id I am expecting